# Reminder: You can vote on tag synonyms

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

We currently have 5 tag synonyms submitted that still need votes. Anyone with voting privileges should exercise them!

1. <s>[pejorative-language](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pejorative-language) and [derogatory](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/derogatory)</s> Completed.
2. <s>[pejorative-language](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pejorative-language) and [insults](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/insults)</s> Completed.
3. [single-word-requests](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/single-word-requests) and [phrase-requests](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/phrase-requests) ([Meta discussion](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4728/6006))
4. <s>[meaning](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/meaning) and [senses](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/senses) ([Meta discussion](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4624/6006))</s> Completed.
5. <s>[abbreviations](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/abbreviations) and [short-form](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/short-form)</s> Completed.

You can find the suggestions here: https://english.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms?filter=suggested&tab=synonym. To vote, click on the left tag and it will show you a little up or down arrow to click on.

Comment: Thanks for bringing this to attention. I never knew how to vote for tag mergers. It takes so many clicks to get there! And there'll all not obvious!

Comment: This is an example of what I don't think is helpful about tags. _Abbreviation_ is strictly a writing term, whereas _short form_ applies to any kind of structure, from sentence down to syllable. I.e, **real** language, not writing. And where's _contraction_ in this schema?

Comment: @JohnLawler: You can obviously vote against any particular tag synonym if you think there is an interesting difference between them. We can always rename [tag:abbreviation] to something more appropriate, too. [tag:contracts] apparently exists as its own tag. I'm still planning on doing more tag clean up over the next few months so there will plenty of opportunity to help us get things into a more useful state.